# Set hidden field using HTML Helper to Date Time Now

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, razor, hiddenfield

I'm looking to do something in ASP.NET MVC 5 to set a hidden field to current date and time. Something like:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CommentTime, new { @Value=DateTime(Now) })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do set like this

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CommentTime, new { @Value=System.DateTime.Now })
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Controller, when creating the model, just set the property:

```
var model = new MyModel
            {
                 CommentTime = DateTime.Now
            };

return View(model);
```

Comment: It could also be set at the Model or ViewModel level too ( In the {get;} ) right?